# Read serial data to winforms

Tags: c#, arduino

Let's start off with that I have no idea what I'm doing. I've done some fancy C# stuff, but with the arduino I'm clueless. Luckily this is the last assignment I have to do with the arduino, so after this I'm done with it.

I have a Adafruit RFID/NFC shield, to, well, read RFIC/NFC tags. This works perfectly with the Adafruit examples. Now I have it logging the ID of the tag to the serial, and I want my C# program to react to it.

I've looked around on the web for examples, but there isn't really much useful stuff to find about this specific piece. Hence why I'm posting a question here. **So far I've tried using the [DataReceivedHandler](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/5274/c-and-arduino-problem-with-serial-port), as well as some other solutions (`port.ReadByte();`, [what is described here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Interfacing-your-arduino-with-a-C-program/?ALLSTEPS) and [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Csharp)).**

But none of it seems to be working correctly. None of the solutions pick up anything the arduino is returning. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 for both the C# and the Arduino. Fist of all, I can run the C# while another instance of VS is keeping the serial console occupied. It didn't result in an error of any kind, which it apparently should have. Yes, the COM port is the correct one (3 on this computer) and yes, the cable works perfectly.

For the arduino I use the following code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_PN532.h>

#define IRQ   (2)
#define RESET (3)  // Not connected by default on the NFC Shield

int ledPin = 11;
uint8_t code[] = { 153, 220, 181, 78, 0, 0, 0 };
boolean firstTime = true;
boolean correct = true;

Adafruit_PN532 nfc(IRQ, RESET);

void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello!");
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  nfc.begin();

  uint32_t versiondata = nfc.getFirmwareVersion();
  if (! versiondata) {
    Serial.print("Didn't find PN53x board");
    while (1); // halt
  }

  // Got ok data, print it out!
  Serial.print("Found chip PN5"); Serial.println((versiondata>>24) & 0xFF, HEX); 
  Serial.print("Firmware ver. "); Serial.print((versiondata>>16) & 0xFF, DEC); 
  Serial.print('.'); Serial.println((versiondata>>8) & 0xFF, DEC);

  // Set the max number of retry attempts to read from a card
  // This prevents us from waiting forever for a card, which is
  // the default behaviour of the PN532.
  nfc.setPassiveActivationRetries(0xFF);

  // configure board to read RFID tags
  nfc.SAMConfig();

  Serial.println("Waiting for an ISO14443A card");
}

void loop(void) {
  boolean success;
  uint8_t uid[] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };  // Buffer to store the returned UID
  uint8_t uidLength;                        // Length of the UID (4 or 7 bytes depending on ISO14443A card type)

  // Wait for an ISO14443A type cards (Mifare, etc.).  When one is found
  // 'uid' will be populated with the UID, and uidLength will indicate
  // if the uid is 4 bytes (Mifare Classic) or 7 bytes (Mifare Ultralight)
  success = nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, &uid[0], &uidLength);

  if (success) {
      if (firstTime) { Serial.println("First time. Writing shit"); }
    Serial.println("Found a card!");
    Serial.print("UID Length: ");Serial.print(uidLength, DEC);Serial.println(" bytes");
    Serial.print("UID Value: ");
    for (uint8_t i=0; i < uidLength; i++) 
    {
        Serial.print(" 0x");Serial.print(uid[i], HEX);
        if (firstTime) { 
            //code[i] = uid[i], HEX;
        };
    }
    /*Serial.println("");
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
        Serial.println(uid[i], HEX);
        uint8_t temp = uid[i], HEX;
        String temp = "0x" + uid[i];
    }-*/

    firstTime = false;
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Let's check it: ");
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < uidLength; i++) {
        //Serial.print("Looking for: "); Serial.println(code[i], HEX);
        Serial.print("Found: "); Serial.println(uid[i], HEX);
        if (code[i] == uid[i]) {
            Serial.println("Found match!");
            correct = true;
        }
        else {
            Serial.print("Wanted: "); Serial.println(code[i], HEX);
            correct = false;
        }
    }

    if (correct) {
        Serial.println("Complete code is correct!");
    }


    // Wait 1 second before continuing
    delay(1000);
  }
  else
  {
    // PN532 probably timed out waiting for a card
    Serial.println("Timed out waiting for a card");
  }
}
```

Yes, this is nearly identical to the adafruit test programs, and no, that doesn't matter. I just need to get this working before Tuesday. I still need to change that the arduino only passes the ID to the serial monitor, but that is something to do when it can communicate with the C#. It needs to communicate in both ways:

- The ID needs to be picked up by the C#
- The C# will return a bool, and the arduino needs to act based on that bool

But I can't get the C# to work with the SerialPort. Can someone help me with how I should approach the serial communication from both ends?

Comment: Thanks for the -1, but can you please explain what is missing? I hate it that you can just -1 a question without giving a description of what is wrong in your opinion

Comment: Step #1, take C# out of the equation.  Download putty or Termite, and see if you can get output from the arduino  to the terminal app.  Maybe look in reddit/r/arduino for more help.  Good Luck. I did not DV.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have to use C# for the assignment. Other team members have already worked on the databaseconnection and the UI. My part was the connection between the arduino and the C#, hence the C# in my question. I'll have a look at the programs you mentioned, maybe I can learn something useful from it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend just worked this out for me. It's dirty, but it gets the job done.

```
    SerialPort serial;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        serial = new SerialPort();
        serial.PortName = "COM4";
        serial.BaudRate = 9600;
        serial.DtrEnable = true;
        serial.Open();

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer_Tick);

        timer.Start();
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String dataFromArduino = serial.ReadLine().ToString();
    }
```

Thanks for the -1 again :p